# How to find what branch was just deleted?

Tags: git, bitbucket

On my organisation bitbucket git page, I deleted a branch and then a few minutes later found that the one I wanted to delete was still there so I went in and deleted it. Now I do not know what branch I deleted by mistake last time. Is there a history log of such changes that I can check or a recycle bin of deleted branches?

The branch was supposed to be created in the submodule, that is why I deleted it. It was in the wrong place.

I went to the branches page for the repository and then under actions, selected delete branch for a branch. But it seems that in hurry I selected the wrong branch.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command

```
git branch -a
```

and it will list all remote branches - even those which were deleted, because they are cached locally.
Then go to bitbucket, and see list of branches there. Compare both lists, and then you will find out which remote branch was actually deleted.